# How to back tab in dbeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

I pressed tab too many times. Usually to undo the tab I press ctrl+[ in vscode. What is the equivalent for dbeaver?

```sql
--For example
                    select productname
                    from products
                    where productid in
                                          (select productid
                                          from
                                          ...
--to return back to this
select productname
from products
where productid in
    (select productid
    from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for dbeaver is `Alt + Tab`

Comment: `Alt+Tab` jump window (windows 10).

Comment: In Windows? My Mac keyboard doesn't have an Alt key. When I select multiple lines in other editors, Shift+Tab removes an indent, but not in DBeaver. I'm not seeing what the de-indent lines block hotkey name is in it...

Comment: `Shift + Tab` is working for me to unintent a highlighted block on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [@Spencer Mathews'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358526/how-to-back-tab-in-dbeaver#:%7E:text=Shift%20%2B%20Tab%20is,at%2019%3A10) method

> `Shift + Tab` is working for me to unintent a highlighted block on Mac.

And I found out that `Shift + Tab` also works to decrease indent on **Windows**